# Webkit bug or intended behaviour? (overflowing DIV and IFRAME)

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit

I've got a problem with IFRAMEs inside an DIV with hidden overflow and I'm curious to know if this is a bug or intended behaviour. It only occurs in Chrome and Safari, FF and IE work fine, so it may be some Webkit specific problem.

My situation is as follows:

- site with DIV where overflow is set to hidden
- this DIV contains an absolutely positioned IFRAME as well as some other elements overflowing the DIVs dimensions
- jQuery function writes some html text to the IFRAME if users clicks a button

Look at this example where everything works as expected:
http://jsbin.com/aqexij/1

Now reload the page with an additional hash character (#) in the url and click the button:
http://jsbin.com/aqexij/1#

In Chrome and Safari this causes the DIV containing the IFRAME to reset the scroll position so that the iframe is on top (in the example above $('#workspace').scrollTop() returns 100 which is exactly the iframes distance from the top).

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like a bug similar to [this](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29520).

Comment: ok, so it's a webkit bug... thanks for the link!